# How to apply a texture to a light through a python script

Tags: python, texturing, lighting

I would like to apply an image texture to my light.
Here is my script but it does not work. I get the following error message: "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'nodes'".

How can I apply a texture to my light with python?

Here is my code
Thanks for your help

```
import bpy
import numpy
import math 
import os
import bmesh

from mathutils import Euler
from bpy import context, data, ops
from math import radians

##Defined the rendering engine used
bpy.context.scene.render.engine = 'CYCLES'

##Light creation
light_data1        = bpy.data.lights.new(name = "Light", type ='SPOT')
light_data1.energy = 276 #Power (W)

## create new object with our light datablock
light_object1 = bpy.data.objects.new(name = "Light", object_data = light_data1)

## link light object
bpy.context.collection.objects.link(light_object1)

## make it active 
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = light_object1

##Light information
light_object1.location        = (0, 0, 15)        #in meters
light_object1.rotation_euler  = (0, 0, 0)        #in radius
light_object1.scale           = (1, 1, 1)      #in meters

############ Material light ####################
#Define the object used
object = bpy.context.active_object

#Enable node tree
object.data.use_nodes = True 

#Active the material of the object chosen
material = object.active_material

#Active the nodes of the object chosen
nodes = material.node_tree.nodes

############ Material example ####################
#Making a material
material = bpy.data.materials.new(name = "Calibration Texture")

#Add an image shader
texImage = material.node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeTexImage')

#Load the image in the image shader
texImage.image = bpy.data.images.load("D:/Documents/Blender/textures/Calibration patterns/Checkerboard-A1-30mm-27x18-1.png")

#Set a localisation of the texture shader
texImage.location = (-400, 270)

############ Connection ####################
#Link the output to the input
#material.node_tree.links.new(bsdf.inputs['Base Color'], texImage.outputs['Color'])
nodes.inputs[0] = texImage.outputs['Color']
```

Comment: Your active_object in the line `material = object.active_material` of the script is a light source which has no material.

Comment: I found the solution, thanks for your answer.
A light, regarding the shading window, have a node, and, I assume, textures can be applied on it.
According to the API commandes, what I would like to do can be achieved with view_layer.active_layer_collection.collection.objects.link(light_object)